# Mobile scrollIntoView on mobile device is not centered (NextJS)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

#### Description

I'm encountering an issue with centering an element while scrolling on mobile browsers because the browser window will minimize when you scroll enough. I've tried various approaches, including using the `react-scroll` library and adjusting CSS properties, but the element doesn't stay consistently centered when I use the function/libraries.

#### Expected Behavior

I expect the centered element to remain in the middle of the viewport as I scroll down the page on mobile browsers.

#### Actual Behavior

Currently, because of the mobile browser window, each of the sections i go to is not centered vertically.

#### Code Samples

```
const scrollToID = (id) => {
    // Close the drawer by changing status to false
    closeDrawer();
    const element = document.getElementById(id);
    if (element) {
      element.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "center",
        inline: "center",
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by just making the browser header stay put and not minimized when users scrolled. I achieved that by using this lines of code on my `globals.css`:

```
  html,
  body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

and I also customized my meta tag to this:

```
export const metadata = {
  title: "MSAF",
  description: "A Portfolio Made By Muhammad Salman Alfarisi",
  name: "viewport",
  content:
    "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, interactive-widget=resize-visual",
};
```